# Move all changes to specific files from the last `n` commits onto a newly created sibling branch?

Tags: git

I recently branched from master, made changes to `n` files, but only `n-k` of the changed files are related to the purpose for branching.

As the title asks, how could I move all changes to specific files (i.e. unrelated to the purposes for branching) from the last `m` commits onto a newly created sibling branch (one with no added commits after the parent)?

Comment: @matt Would it be correct to say "I want the file state from the current branch's HEAD committed/moved onto a sibling branch"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you say:

> The updates made to each of the k files are spread across m new commits on this branch (after the parent)

That seems to show a misconception.

Commits don’t contain changes. They contain file states. And they don’t contain just the files that were changed. They contain all the files.

So here you are at the end of your branch. The commit you are on contains the states of all the files. There is no need to look in any other commit.

More important, the working tree contains the states of all the files.  Everything right now is as it should be. The only regret is that you wish you had recorded these file states distributed over two different branches instead of on one branch.

So if you wish the current state of your files on this branch had been recorded on two different branches, then you will have to roll back this entire branch and start over:

1. Reset mixed back to the commit where you diverged to start this branch. This keeps the current states of all your files in the working tree, but removes the commits that recorded those states onto this branch.
2. Make your new branch but don’t get on to it.
3. Add and commit just the files that apply to the old branch.
4. Now checkout the new branch, and add and commit everything (because that is all that remains).

Comment: I meant to respond saying thanks for the explanation, but never got to. :) While I knew `git reset --soft` was a solution, my misconception led me to wonder if there were other ways of solving my original problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

By stashing them. ([`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))

- First, add and commit the `n-k` files on your current branch
- stash the rest (any file still currently modified, and not yet added to the index).

Create your new sibling branch and git stash pop those files.

Comment: The updates made to each of the `k` files are spread across `m` new commits on this branch (after the parent). I could soft reset to the ancestor commit and follow your steps, but I was curious if there were any other approaches I could follow.

Comment: @SeanPianka The soft reset is probably easier, at lest to stash and move the files.